# Criar um ficheiro em php

Tags: php

Este código o que faz é criar um arquivo somente. O arquivo `receitas.txt` eu consigo listar todas as receitas, mas se não houver, quando vou listar da erro.

O que eu quero é clicar no listar e se não houver o arquivo, criar ele:

```
function lerFicheiro(){
    $rec = array();
    $file = './receitas.txt';
    $fh=fopen($file,'r') or die ('Nao foi possivel abrir o ficheiro!');
    $data = fread($fh, filesize($file)) or die ('Nao foi possivel abrir o ficheiro!');;
    fclose($fh);
    $regReceita = explode("\n", $data);
    foreach ($regReceita as $item){
        $registo=explode(";", $item);
        if (count($registo) > 1) {
            $rec[] = array('receita' => $registo[0], 'descricao' => $registo[1]);   
        }
    }
    return $rec;    
}
```

[image: Mensagem de erro: Warning: rfread(): Length parameter must be greater than 0]
<sup>**Fonte:** imgur.com/a/7XZvr</sup>

Comment: Megaluk, explique melhor o seu problema, se não fica complicado ajudá-lo.

Comment: Este código o que faz é cria um ficheiro só se guardar alguma coisa no ficheiro e se o ficheiro estiver criado se houver receitas.txt eu consigo listar todas as receitas mas se nao houver quando vou listar da erro eu quero clicar no listar e o ficheiro criasse sozinho

Comment: Quando precisar adicionar detalhes, clique em "Editar" na resposta, e inclua-os.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize o `fopen($file,'w')` (até porque você quer escrever no arquivo também correto !?) (caso só for leitura, use o "a"):

```
function lerFicheiro(){
    $rec = array();
    $file = './receitas.txt';
    $fh=fopen($file,'w') or die ('Nao foi possivel abrir o ficheiro!');
    $data = fread($fh, filesize($file)) or die ('Nao foi possivel abrir o ficheiro!');
    fclose($fh);
    $regReceita = explode("\n", $data);
    foreach ($regReceita as $item){
        $registo=explode(";", $item);
        if (count($registo) > 1) {
            $rec[] = array('receita' => $registo[0], 'descricao' => $registo[1]);   
        }
    }
    return $rec;    
}
```

Opções:

**‘r’** – Abre somente para leitura; coloca o ponteiro no começo do arquivo.

**‘r+’** – Abre para leitura e gravação; coloca o ponteiro no começo do arquivo.

**‘w’** – Abre somente para gravação; coloca o ponteiro no começo do arquivo e apaga o conteúdo que já foi escrito. Se o arquivo não existir, tentar criá-lo.

**‘w+’** – Abre para leitura e escrita; coloca o ponteiro no início do arquivo e apaga o conteúdo que já foi escrito. Se o arquivo não existir, tentar criá-lo.

**‘a’** – Abre o arquivo somente para escrita; coloca o ponteiro no fim do arquivo. Se o arquivo não existir, tentar criá-lo.

**‘a+’** – Abre o arquivo para leitura e gravação; coloca o ponteiro no fim do arquivo. Se o arquivo não existir, tentar criá-lo.

> Eu ja tentei isso aqui esta o erro que me aparece -imgur.com/a/7XZvr – Megaluk

Verifique o tamanho do arquivo antes do `fread()`:

```
if(filesize($file) > 0)
```

-

```
function lerFicheiro(){
        $rec = array();
        $file = './receitas.txt';
        $fh=fopen($file,'w') or die ('Nao foi possivel abrir o ficheiro!');

       if(filesize($file) > 0) {
           $data = fread($fh, filesize($file)) or die ('Nao foi possivel abrir o ficheiro!');
       } else {
           echo 'Arquivo vazio';
           $data = "";
        }
        fclose($fh);
        $regReceita = explode("\n", $data);
        foreach ($regReceita as $item){
            $registo=explode(";", $item);
            if (count($registo) > 1) {
                $rec[] = array('receita' => $registo[0], 'descricao' => $registo[1]);   
            }
        }
        return $rec;    
    }
```

Comment: Eu ja tentei isso aqui esta o erro que me aparece -https://imgur.com/a/7XZvr

Comment: Inclui na resposta, tente novamente...

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/7XZvr Isso significa que seu arquivo está vazio. Adicionei um `echo` que irá imprimir isso. Mas você pode colocar `$data = ""`

Comment: @Megaluk evite apagar os comentários, se não atrapalha que pode estar com o mesmo problema.

Comment: Adicionei na resposta o `echo` e `$data = ""`

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda esta tudo a funcionar

Comment: @Megaluk não se esqueça de marcar como resolvido, assim ajuda ao próximo. ;]